# Finding all paths in a directed graph with cycles

Tags: algorithm, common-lisp

I am working on a problem which requires finding all paths between two nodes in a directed graph. The graph may have cycles.

Notice that this particular implementation approach is an iterative DFS.

Several approaches I've considered are as follows -

- BFS does not appear to have a way to neatly manage this kind of pathing relationships between nodes.
- I don't see an easy mechanism for a DFS recursive algorithm to pass up the path when the terminating node is found. (Likely enough it could be done, if I implement a Maybe monad kind of thing).
- Creating a GRAPH-PARENT routine. That would add a decent amount of churn (& bugs) in the existing code.

Abstractly, what needs to happen is a tree needs to be generated, with the start node as root, and all leafs are the terminating nodes. Each path from leaf to root is a legal path. That is what a recursive DFS would trace out.

I'm reasonably sure it can be done here, but I don't see exactly how to do it.

I've defined a protocol for this algorithm where GRAPH-EQUAL and GRAPH-NEXT can be defined for arbitrary objects.

The debug node type is a SEARCH-NODE, and it has the data accessor SEARCH-NODE-DATA.

```
(defun all-paths (start end)
  (let ((stack (list start))
        (mark-list (list start))   ;I've chosen to hold marking information local to all-paths, instead of marking the objects themselves.
        (all-path-list '()))       ; Not used yet, using debug statements to think about the problem
    (do  ()  ;; intializing no variables
     ;; While Stack still has elements
         ((not stack))          
      (let ((item (pop stack)))
    ;; I'm looking at the item.
    (format t "I: ~a~%" (search-node-data item)) 
    (cond ((graph-equal item end)
           (format t "*Q: ~a~%" (loop for var in stack collect (search-node-data var)))
           ;;Unmark the terminal node so we can view it it next time.
           (setf mark-list (remove item mark-list))))

        (loop for next in (graph-next item)
           do        
            (cond ((not (in next mark-list :test #'graph-equal))
                    ;; mark the node
                    (push next mark-list)
                    ;;Put it on the stack
                    (push next stack))))))))
```

Answer (score 1):

See [A Very General Method for Computing Shortest Paths](http://r6.ca/blog/20110808T035622Z.html) for an algorithm that can return all paths in a graph (even when there are cycles) as regular expressions over the alphabet of edges in finite time (assuming a finite graph).

Comment: Hm. That's a excruciatingly dense paper. I am disinclined to try to use it due to the complexity of extracting the algorithm into Lisp, as well as the requirement to interface the existing code against the representation.

Comment: The short version is "use Floyd's algorithm". The jist of the paper is that Floyd's algorithm works over a very general mathematical structure - a *-semiring - and demonstrates the use of said algorithm over various *-semirings.

Comment: I would phrase the short version as follows.  Consider your graph as a DFA with initial state your starting node and final state your ending node and give all your edges unique labels and use the set of labels as your alphabet.  The language accepted by this DFA represents the set of all paths from your start node to your end node.  You can, if you want, compute a regular expression for this language by using the McNaughton-Yamada algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the path list (`mark-list`) along with the nodes, since that is part of the state. I've renamed it `path` in this code:

```
(defun all-paths (start end)
  (let ((stack (list '(start (start)))) ; list of (node path) elements
        (all-path-list '()))
    (do  ()
      ((not stack))          
      (let ((item (pop stack)))
        (let ((node (first item))
              (path (second item)))
          (format t "I: ~a~%" (search-node-data node)) 
          (cond ((graph-equal node end)
                 (format t "*Q: ~a~%"
                         (loop for var in path
                               collect (search-node-data var)))))
          (loop for next in (graph-next node)
                do        
                (cond ((not (in next path :test #'graph-equal))
                       (push (list next (cons next path)) stack)))))))))
```

Comment: Your modifications don't work, fyi. stack is initialized in error.